# self intersecting polygon SQl

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a sql to query one land parcel for intersections between itself. I can do this fairly easy in QGIS using topology checker but i don’t know why this does not produce the correct results.

```
    select * from land_parcel as a     
join  land_parcel as b where     
ST_Intersects (a.geom,b.geom) and a.gid <>b.gid
```

Comment: It is written in your question, actually but are we speaking only about polygons? Are there multipolygons as well? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: they are polygons only. I am using postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Two commands that should help you test the geometry are [ST_IsSimple](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsSimple.html) and [ST_IsValid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html).  Once you have identified the bad geometry you can use the plpgsql [cleangeometry](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiCleanPolygons) function which is available from the link on the website (which also gives suggestions on how to roll-your-own proceedure).

Comment: ST_valid shows that all the geometries are correct and ST_IsSimple shows false indicating that they are indeed intersections. So how do I write a sql to show these intersection. I need to create a view to show where they are self intersecting polygons

Comment: Have a look at the page linked to the cleangeometry function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two queries with PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
    a.gid,
    a.geom
FROM land_parcel AS a
    LEFT JOIN land_parcel b ON a.gid <> b.gid
        WHERE ST_Intersects (a.geom,b.geom)
```

...

```
SELECT
    a.gid,
    a.geom
FROM land_parcel AS a, (SELECT gid, geom FROM land_parcel) b
    WHERE ST_Intersects (a.geom,b.geom) 
        AND a.gid <> b.gid
```